# Show a splash screen while loading a view controller from another view controller

Tags: ios, view, uinavigationcontroller, splash-screen

I have an app that opens with a splash screen (Default.png), then loads the first view (`ViewController1`) in a navigation controller.  Straight away, an instance of `ViewController2` (VC2) is created, and pushed onto the navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:NO];
```

So when I run the app, the default image is displayed, then the view of `ViewController1` is briefly displayed until `ViewController2` is loaded (and then displayed).

How can I stop the brief display of `ViewController1`?  Can I extend the display of Default.png until VC2 is displayed, or cover `ViewController1` with the Default.png image until VC2 shows?

Thanks so much.

Comment: you can add a UIImageView with splash image on [window addSubview:splashImage]; just before executing the code [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES]; and then remove it in VC2's viewDiDAppear

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing you want to do is to show VC2 without showing VC1, in the `viewDidLoad` method of your VC1 you can do `self.view.hidden = YES;` then push the VC2 without animation

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, you want VC2 to be your starting point with VC1 as your ad-hoc splash screen. The default.png images should be a way to mirror the look of your app to give the impression your app is starting and working faster than it may appear. (This is taken from [Apple's HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1))

You may want to consider making VC1 your new splashscreen/loading screen. You could make it into a simple waiting or loading page then load VC2 once everything in your app has been taken care of. Default.png could be an image of the loading screen and would give the impression your app is loading right away.

There are many differing opinions of how to approach this issue. You will ultimately have to decide which method is best for you and your application.

One final thought, you could load directly to VC2 and just present a loading progress view. I have used [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to lock the user out while I load information or perform tasks they need to wait for. This could be another option. Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UIImageView` to VC1 with Default.png, then remove it in `viewDidDisappear:`.

Comment: If I simply place a UIImageView in VC1 (at top) I get an error (SIGABRT), I think because VC2 accesses some data it believes is on the top view of VC1. Any way to programmatically fix this (perhaps by adding the UIImageView in VC1?)

Comment: You can put the `UIImageView` to the back, and set the alpha of the other views to 0, then change all the alpha values to 1 on `viewDidDisappear:`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can modify the Default.png behaviour. I would suggest you create an UIImageView in ViewController1 with Default.png as its image. Give it the exact same size as the screen and add it as a subview that completetely covers it. That way you will see Deafult.png twice and after it will go to ViewController2